# Naming tikz umlpackage with path reference: No shape named X is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I want to declare a packages name inside the `umlpackage`environment not only as the package's name but the reference path to it.
It seems, there might be a problem when using `.` (full stops). The document won't compile if if try to run following code.

Below a mwe:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{umlpackage}{path/to/package}
    % swapping path/to/package with path.to.package will result in following error:
    % Package pgf Error: No shape named `path' is known.
    \umlclass[x=0, y=0]{ClassA}{
    - fieldA: Field}
    {
     + methodA(fieldA: Field ): void
    }
    \end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Possibly, the fault lies in the `tikz-uml.sty` ~ line 324:

`\StrSubstitute{\tikzumlPackage@nodeName}{.}{@POINT@}{\tikzumlPackage@nodeName}%`

I'm not that confident with configuring my LaTeX environment, but this command should replace every `.`with the macro `@POINT@`, right? `@POINT@` is what exactly? How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an optional argument `name` that you can use to set the node name instead of using the label as a node name.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{umlpackage}[name=path/to/package]{path.to.package}
    \umlclass[x=0, y=0]{ClassA}{
    - fieldA: Field}
    {
     + methodA(fieldA: Field ): void
    }
    \end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]